# Terminating a bash shell script running in the background

Tags: shell, shell-script, process, kill, ps

I often use `bash` shell scripts to run simple commands for many different files.  For example, suppose that I have the following `bash` shell script, called `script.sh`, that runs the program/command `foo` on three text files `"a.txt"`, `"b.txt"`, `"c.txt"`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for strname in "a" "b" "c"
do
foo $strname".txt"
done
```

Also, suppose that `foo $strname".txt"` is slow, so the execution of the script will take a long time (hours or days, for example).  Because of this, I would like to use `nohup` so that the execution continues even if the terminal is closed or disconnected.  I would also like the script to immediately go to the background, so I will use the `&` operator.  Thus I will use the following command to call `script.sh`:

```
nohup bash script.sh &
```

This works fine for running the script in the background and without hangup, but now suppose that I would like to terminate the execution at some point for some reason.  How can I do this?

The problem that I have encountered is that, by looking at `top`, I see only the `foo` corresponding to `"a.txt"`.  I can terminate that `foo` call, but then the `foo` corresponding to `"b.txt"` gets called and then I have to terminate that one as well, and so on.  For tens or hundreds of text files specified in the `for` loop, it becomes a pain to terminate every `foo`, one by one!  So somehow I need to instead terminate the shell script *itself*, not the *particular* calls issued from the shell script.

When I type the command

```
ps -u myusername
```

where `myusername` is my username, I get a list of processes that I'm running.  But I see two different process IDs called `bash`.  How do I know which of these processes, if any, corresponds to my original call `nohup bash script.sh &`?

Comment: @Andrew ,Do both of the process show nohup mentioned in the command ? .... alternatively you can try ps -aWu Andrew and check if you get a locate a single long entry with nohup .... does it help ?

Comment: As an aside, your quoting is wacky. `for s in a b c;  do foo "$s".txt; done`

Comment: @NSD: No, the `nohup` will be long gone by the time you bring up a process listing to see the job you started. You can look at the "niceness" column in the `ps` output but the answers here are more useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, `ps` will not show the parameters the program was called with. The options `-f` and `-l` both will show the full call.

```
ps -fu username
```

will result in output that looks like:

```
username 23464 66.7  0.0  11400   628 pts/5    R    15:28   1:40 bash script.sh
```

Comment: That's moderately useful, but does not disambiguate multiple processes with the same arguments.

Answer (score 16):

You have a couple of options.  Since your process is running in the background, you can use `jobs` to find it:

```
nohup bash script.sh &
...
jobs
[1]+ Running    nohup bash script.sh &
kill %1
jobs
[1]+ Terminated nohup bash script.sh &
```

You can also use `pkill` to search the process table for a command line matching; viz:

```
pkill -f script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ps` output (with e.g. `ps aux`) include the parent's process ID. Kill the parent `bash`, and its children, too, will be terminated.

For an ASCII visualization of the process tree, try `pstree -p` with a few background processes running.